# Not sure what Compiler is complaining about, and how to find the solution

Tags: c++, cygwin

I have a huge list of errors that come up when i try to compile source code under cygwin.. My best approach to learning programming is hitting it hard, and trail and error. So even if my C++ knowledge is very basic, I am still really new, so please when you explain can I please ask that you use baby talk for a lack of a better word lol. When I type in 'make' under the source directory is gives me these errors. A friend of mine, we are friends on a MUD, he has been a programmer for 35 years and he says to me that the compiler is not liking that the function is returning a pointer and to change all the "return ''''" to return strdup('''')

Please let me know what you guys think. Thanks

Underneath is only a very smalllll part of the syntax that was given to me after I typed in make in Cygwin. I hope someone has the time to explain this to me, thank you.

```
$ make
make -s smaug
  -Compiling o/imc.o....
imc.c:106:1: error: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Werror=write-strings]
 };
 ^
imc.c:106:1: error: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Werror=write-strings]
imc.c:106:1: error: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Werror=write-strings]
imc.c:106:1: error: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Werror=write--strings]
imc.c:106:1: error: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Werror=write-strings]
imc.c:106:1: error: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Werror=write-strings]
imc.c: In function ‘char* color_itom(const char*, CHAR_DATA*)’:
imc.c:393:14: error: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Werror=write-strings]
   return "";
          ^
imc.c: In function ‘char* color_mtoi(const char*)’:
imc.c:414:14: error: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Werror=write-strings]
   return "";
          ^
imc.c: In function ‘char* imccapitalize(const char*)’:
imc.c:525:35: error: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Werror=conversion]
   strcap[i] = tolower( str[i] );
                               ^
imc.c:527:35: error: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Werror=conversion]
strcap[0] = toupper( strcap[0] );
                               ^
imc.c: In function ‘void imc_new_channel(const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*, bool, int, const char*)’:
imc.c:1089:13: error: conversion to ‘short int’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Werror=conversion]
c->level = perm;
         ^

       ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:101: recipe for target 'o/imc.o' failed
make[1]: *** [o/imc.o] Error 1
Makefile:46: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Ok below is the code where it shows error for line 106: 1 and 393: Its a very lonnng .c file I am sure you guys don't want to upload the whole thing, but here is the portion of it, and according to Visual 2013 here is starting point line 106 and 393: i am not sure when cygwin says the line number where the error took place if that doesn't include white space and comments, but here is 106 and 393 according to VS:

line 106

```
SITEINFO *this_imcmud;
```

line 393

```
if( IMCIS_SET( IMCFLAG( ch ), IMC_COLORFLAG ) )
```

Comment: Post your code, please.

Comment: @DavidHammen Let me continue: ... the relevant (and exemplary) one, and not tons of equivalent error messages.

Comment: In particular, what is line 106 of im.c?

Comment: ok I uploaded the code that gave the error

Answer (score 4):

You should show your code, but your problems are:

1. Somewhere you're doing something like:

   ```
   char *x = "hello";
   ```

   It should be:

   ```
   const char *x = "hello";
   ```
2. Similarly, `char* color_itom(const char*, CHAR_DATA*)` should return `const char *` if you want to return string literals from it.
3. `strcap` is defined as a `char` array, but you're putting the `int` values returned by `tolower` and `toupper` in there somewhere.  Either change the type or put in an explicit cast.
4. Same for `c->level = perm`.  Either add an explicit cast or change the type of `c->level` to match the type of `perm`.

Answer (score 1):

The error:

```
deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
```

is caused by using string literal to initiaize char*, e.g.

`char* str = "something";`

This should read:

`const char* str = "something";`